# How to create a Dart form

Tags: dart

My problem: building a Dart form according to the book. Below, my basic sample that looks like JS. It works fine but I get this warning: `The getter value is not defined for the class Element`.

My question: how can I write a better Dart code to avoid this warning message? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="enter-x">
    <input type="number" min="0" id="enter-y">

    <input type="button" id="result" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" id="raz" value="Reset">

    <input type="text" id="s" readonly>
</form>
```

DART:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';

main() {
    document.querySelector('#result').onClick.listen((e) {
        calculateS();
    });
}

calculateS() {
    var x = int.parse(document.querySelector('#enter-x').value);
    var y = int.parse(document.querySelector('#enter-y').value);
      var surface = (x * y).toString();
    document.querySelector('#s').value = surface;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart helps with hints and warning to find errors in your program.
The generic `Element` doesn't have a `value` field. The Dart program is still valid and should work as expected and doesn't cause any errors or warnings at runtime because the actually returned element is the more specialized `TextInputElement` or `NumberInputElement` which has a `value` field.

To silence the analyzer, make this more clear by adding a "cast"

```
calculateS() {
  var x = int.parse((document.querySelector('#enter-x') as NumberInputElement).value);
  var y = int.parse((document.querySelector('#enter-y') as NumberInputElement).value);
  var surface = (x * y).toString();
  (document.querySelector('#s') as TextInputElement).value = surface;
}
```

Try it at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4edacb9702dc61fc6b81)

See also:

- https://api.dartlang.org/1.12.0/dart-html/InputElement-class.html
- [Dart 'query' explicit cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863518)
- [What is the syntax for implicit cast operator in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950515)
- https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#operators